# Why does QGIS 2.0 and SQL Server say Data source name not found and no default driver specified?

Tags: sql-server, qgis-2

I've just started using QGIS 2.0 after using 1.8 for sometime. However I'm having an issue getting a SQL Server connection, I'm using the same settings as as used in 1.8 but I keep gettting an error when I try to 'Test Connection' and I don't understand why.
Here's the error:

'[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver   specified QODBC3: Unable to connect'

Comment: I'm having this too, but I'm on Ubuntu and wonder if I need the SQL server client tools loaded... what OS are you on?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simlar Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283460/error-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-defau

To quote SQLRyan:

> If you're working with an x64 server, keep in mind that there are
>   different ODBC settings for x86 and x64 applications. The "Data
>   Sources (ODBC)" tool in the Administrative Tools list takes you to the
>   x64 version. To view/edit the x86 ODBC settings, you'll need to run
>   that version of the tool manually:
>
> %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe (%windir% is usually C:\Windows) When
>   your app runs as x64, it will use the x64 data sources, and when it
>   runs as x86, it will use those data sources instead.